# mongodb - proper way of data modeling

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that represents users, with their names and roles, where a role can be admin, user or guest (lets assume one role per user). Basically I'm new to mongodb. What I would do in a relational database is keep two linked tables, one for users and one for roles. I'm not sure what is the best way to handle this in mongodb though. For instance, should my collection look like so?

```
{ {"name": "John", role: "admin"}, {"name": "Jack", role: "user"} }
```

In this case, if I have a typo in one of the roles, then I would have to update all the users with that role. What scheme would you suggest?

Comment: If you have a typo in one of the key names you would also have the same issue. The value used for a role should be predefined somewhere (possibly in another collection) and used identically in each relevant document. In a UI context; The role would be selected from a dropdown and not typed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the best way to do it and you're right if you want to change a role name you have to update all the item in the collection but it's a single command.

The benefit would be also to have several roles for a single user with requiring to add a table, like this:

```
{ {"name": "John", roles: ["admin","user"]}, {"name": "Jack", roles: ["user"]} }
```

But if the role part start to grow, with some access right, having the possibility to share the same right between users, etc.. you can also create a second table with roles, and juste reference the id in the user table, just like a join in SQL

Answer (score 0):

@tomsoft's solution is great.

I give you my piece of advice: when you have a multiple enumerate, traduce "enumerate" like a list. Its much easier for me do this.

Another example:
Vehicles is an enumerate: you can have motorbike, scooter, car, truck...

But you must be wary with atomic enumerates, like favourite fruit:
[Banana, Apple, Peach, Grape] You only must to choose one!